# Could my code cause a crash when creating a new file and directory under Windows 7?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, windows-xp

I have had some problems earlier which caused my program to crash in all Windows OS because I did not create a new file/directory for my file. Then I have assured that I have created file/folder before initializing ect. Now my program works in Windows XP but it doesn't work in Windows 7. By saying that it works I mean that it creates a file/folder needed for my program. By not working I mean that the file/folder isn't created in windows 7.

Could this code be the cause of the crash under Windows 7? If so, how could I fix it?

```
    private static string dir = Environment.GetFolderPath
        (Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) + @"\folder\";
    private static string file = dir + @"\Settings.txt";
    private string text;

    public void CheckFileStatus()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
        {
            DirectoryInfo directory = Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
        }
        if (!File.Exists(file))
        {
            using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(file))
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you say crash - do you mean throw an exception? If so, what?

Comment: @Prescott, There is no exception presented. simply it say that program has crashed; send report to Microsoft... I can't check any details because I'm not the one with Windows 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The program files directory in Windows 7 can only be written to with elevated privileges. Are you running your code as an administrator? It's also bad practice to write to the program files folder. You should be using the %appdata% folder.

Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) to see the various special folders. You will likely want to use either `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` or `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData`. This will allow you to write data without needing elevated privileges.

Comment: I don't think that privileges are set to admin on PC of my tester.

Comment: @NewHelpNeeder: Is your tester able to right-click and run as administrator? If not, are you installing your program via Wix or some other type of installer software? If so, you can mark the executable as requiring elevated privileges. However, the issue really is that you need to save the settings to the proper location (not program files).

Comment: my tester is kind of blank on how to deal with such thing. I'm trying to simplify this as much as possible. Your solution seems very nice.

Comment: @NewHelpNeeder: Give it a whirl. It should solve your problem (and is a better practice, especially in the days of UAC).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create folders in Program Files without being having elevated privileges (ie acting as an Administrator) on Windows Vista and Windows 7. There are generally better places to put settings files that should be writable by any user.

`Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` or `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`  is generally the place for user specific application data which is most likely what you want.

The difference being that in a domain, `ApplicationData` will be placed in your roaming profile and be shared between computers on the domain, while `LocalApplicationData` is for that very machine only.

For home users or if you don't specifically want the data to be shared between machines, probably `LocalApplicationData` is better. That way you know it won't cause problems on a domain if you end up writing computer specific data in it.

There is also `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` which allows for sharing the same data between all users on the computer, but while that may seem convenient, consider that any user on the machine can then change settings of a program that is later run by you which may cause security implications.

Comment: Should I instead store information to for example My Documents? Or which folder should be used?

Comment: I do like the idea of LocalApp folder which would be best which would protect data from other computer users. Thanks for this information.